# How to check if user is signed in the frontend of swift App. Backend in python/django-rest-framework

Tags: python, swift, authentication, django-rest-framework, frontend

Im trying to make an IOS app with a frontend coded in swift and the back in python using django's rest api.
I have a tab bar controller set up with two tabs, one ultimately connected to a HomeViewController. I have used firebaseAuth, in which I would normally use a firebase function that looked roughly like this

```
if firebase.Auth.currentUser != nil {
   let vc = HomeViewController()
   present(vc, animated:True)
}
```

However, to the best of my knowledge, django's rest api does not have a function of doing so, and so I have been stuck for a few hours now trying to figure this out.
Currently, I am planning on using the cached access token, retrieved on registration/login and sending a get request which returns the users information. (username and email). Then creating a function to decode the data which returns a boolean.
I plan on making a struct

```
struct AuthenticatedUser: Codable, Hashable {
let username: String
let email: String
}
```

If it does not confirm to the appropriate struct, the json decoder will fail. (This would be because the get request returned an error as the token was deleted. (In the process of logging out, i would delete the users tokens).
Finally, I will end up with something like this

```
if decodeData == false {
   let vc = HomeViewController()
   present(vc, animated:True)
}
```

Im sure this would work, but even as someone new to programming I can tell that this code seems longwinded, messy and most likely considered as bad code.
I was wondering if anyone had any improvement/new methods (preferably new methods) on combatting this problem.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first your app does not strictly need to know *a priori* if the current user (which is some data stored persistently within the app) is signed-in in order to access protected user resources successfully (eventually).

The mechanism required in order to make this work, can be entirely embedded transparently into the "client network code", and your views and other parts of your app which perform "protected data access" do not need to know anything about the login scheme, or whether the user is registered or signed-in.

What is *signed-in* anyway?

What is *registered*?

What is a *user*?

Assuming you are using the more common login schemes (OpenID Connect or an custom scheme based in OAuth) which is based on user authentication, user consent and a bearer token, these questions can be answered as follows:

A user which is a struct containing some data about a real user is the identity which has been successfully authenticated. This information is available after user authentication and authorization which usually are the first two steps in the "register user" flow. This can happen on a third party identity provider, but can also be included in your domain server.

Once you have an authenticated user, the app registers this user in our domain database as part of the registration flow. That is, after this step, your user is *registered*, and that means, it can access the services provided by your domain server.

A user also can "unregister" and its private data and especially, the "user" record on the domain server will be deleted or marked "unregistered".

The processes running on the front end for this, can run on the device or anywhere, for example a web application or a desk top application.

Now, what should be immediately become clear is, that given a certain app on a certain device and just by querying local state, an app *never* can determine a priori if a user is registered or not, even if the app has a user info.

Now, suppose an app has a "current user" info, and that the user has been *registered*, but it is not yet "signed-in".

Signing in means, that the app receives a refresh token and an access token. The access token is the key to access protected user resources. When doing this, no user info is required, the access token is implicitly associated to this user.

The refresh token acts as a key to get a new access token, whose expiration time is much longer, possibly quite long, so that it literally never expires (not recommended).

The expiration duration of an access token is usually in the minutes. So, it is quite common that the access token expires all the time.

The access token will be required when accessing a protected resource, so it will be needed for every protected access.

When it is expired, the server sends a very specific unambiguous status code. So, your client code can act accordingly, which means:

1. push the request on a queue
2. use the refresh token and ask for a new access token on a certain refresh-token endpoint
3. Retry the request with the renewed access token

This mechanism is completely transparent to the higher level code and can be implemented quite deeply in the client network code.

Now, in the event that the refresh token is expired too, you again get an unambiguously status code from the refresh-token endpoint.

In this case, it is clear what to do:

1. Require the user to sign-in again
2. Step one returns a are refresh token and also access token
3. Retry the request.

It is clear, that this requires user interaction and will interrupt the current active flow. It should also be obvious, that an app can also not determine a priory if the refresh token has been expired.

Ideally, this "sign-in-again" flow can be pushed on top of any other flow which happens to access a protected resource. Alternatively, just let the refresh-token request fail without opening a sign-in flow, showing a clear error message hinting that the user needs to sign-in again.

The consequences of this is, that you have to *try* (or just *can* try!) to access a protected resource in order to find out whether a user is signed in or even registered.

This all has to be implemented in the client network code. Good luck! ;)

Comment: Just occurred to me that I completely forgot to respond. Thanks for answering my question, Its helped alot!. @CouchDeveloper